# How to use "iOS Local Device" in Visual 2022 preview MAUI project Windows

Tags: maui

there's a button on the Windows version of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.0 Preview 4.0 when we choose test platform (local device, emulator...) with "iOS Local Device".
=> Will it mean that it's possible to plug an iphone to a windows laptop and test Maui app on Iphone?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use `iOS Local Device` when you are using hot Restart feature without using MAC, but Hot restart has some limitations , you will still need a Mac machine to do a full compilation, signing, and deployment if you want to publish your app.